# Getting setup.py issues installing packages on Pycharm

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, pycharm, setup.py

pretty new to Python/PyCharm and I'm having some issues installing packages. Specifically I'm having issues with BeautifulSoup. I get this error when trying to install it using Project Interpreter:

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup
 Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 20, in <module

----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/5d/13rfvrgn3b5c1n52l2ngrhzh0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging1.tmp/BeautifulSoup
```

I've tried all the other solutions that I can find on the web such as running `pip install --user BeautifulSoup`, I've updated SetupTools and Pip to be running the most recent version, etc. This only happens when I try to install on the Python 3.4 Project Interpreter.

If I switch to the Python 2.6.8 Interpreter, it will install. However when I try  `import BeautifulSoup`, it says package not found. I'm sure this is an easier fix but if someone could please help that would be great! I'm getting pretty frustrated at this point. :/

Comment: The traceback is cut off.  Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Comment: Kevin, that's literally all it says in the Command Output of the Project Interpreter. Is there a way to show more that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Okay so I used pip install --user beautifulsoup4 instead of just beautifulsoup and it seems to have worked? We'll see if I have any problems in the future. Thanks sobolevn and Kevin!